# Connect to kubernetes container and curl inside of it in Java

Tags: java, batch-file, kubernetes, curl, cmd

I'm trying to connect to one of my containers inside my cluster and execute multiple curl commands programmatically in Java.

To solve this I've written the following code:

```
    String[] executeResetServerCachesBatFileCommand = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "resetServerCaches.bat"};
    ProcessBuilder cacheResetBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(executeResetServerCachesBatFileCommand);
    cacheResetBuilder.directory(new File("C:/Program Files/PuTTY/"));
    Process cacheReset = cacheResetBuilder.start();
```

The goal is to run a .bat file which contains multiple commands line by line.

The commands inside the .bat file are as follows:

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty <podname> --namespace=<namespace> -- /bin/bash (connect to container)
curl -X DELETE -H "Authorization: Basic <auth> <url>
curl -X DELETE -H "Authorization: Basic <auth> <url>
curl -X DELETE -H "Authorization: Basic <auth> <url>
```

Don't wonder, I haven't written down the original values.

The bat file gets executed, so that is working. The problem is that after the first command in the .bat file (connect to container, which works) the rest of the commands are not executed or skipped.

I've put commands just as ipconfig or dir on the first line and then connect to the container to debug the problem. I found out that ipconfig and dir get executed just as the connecting part. So the problem is that the kubectl exec command take some seconds to finish and the rest is somehow skipped or bugged out.

I also tried working with "&" and "&&" to wait for the first command but that didn't work either.

I've went to many stackoverflow topics and googled but I couldn't make it.
Maybe someone can help me.

Best regards,
Julian

Comment: Have you tried ```start kubectl...```?

Comment: Why don't you just use Java to perform the HTTP requests?